# static selector/predicate in LINQ statements?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I recently came across this syntax:

```cs
var projection = myCollection.Select(static f => f.MyProperty);
```

and it's the first time I'd seen this `static` predicate syntax in a Select statement.

That said, I've yet to find any solid documentation on the benefits/drawbacks of this. Can somebody enlighten me?

Thanks!

Comment: See [Static anonymous functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/static-anonymous-functions). "Motivation: Avoid unintentionally capturing state from the enclosing context, which can result in unexpected retention of captured objects or unexpected additional allocations."

Comment: Shameless plug: [Understanding the cost of C# delegates](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/understanding-the-cost-of-csharp-delegates/ "Understanding the cost of C# delegates")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the C# documentation,

> Beginning with C# 9.0, you can apply the static modifier to a lambda expression to prevent unintentional capture of local variables or instance state by the lambda

In other news, it just prevents you from accessing the object the lambda was defined in (`this` and `base`)

EG, this is legal:

```cs
return Collection.Select(f =>
{
    if (this.Type == "Thing")
        return f.Value;
    return 0;
}).Sum();
```

And this is not:

```cs
//                       static declared here...
//                       vvvvvv 
return Collection.Select(static f =>
{
//      ...but this instance is referenced here!
//      vvvv
    if (this.Type == "Thing")
        return f.Value;
    return 0;
}).Sum();
```

### Summary Benchmarks

```cs
public long Benchmark() => Collection.Select(static f => f.Value).Sum();
```

| Method | N | Type | Mean | Error | StdDev | Median | Code Size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NonStatic | 1000 | Class | 21.49 us | 1.560 us | 4.574 us | 18.90 us | 2,663 B |
| Static | 1000 | Class | 20.83 us | 1.279 us | 3.750 us | 19.30 us | 2,665 B |
| NonStatic | 1000 | Struct | 18.63 us | 1.274 us | 3.756 us | 16.20 us | 1,734 B |
| Static | 1000 | Struct | 19.57 us | 1.391 us | 4.035 us | 19.10 us | 1,734 B |
| NonStatic | 100000 | Class | 1,505.53 us | 117.721 us | 335.865 us | 1,495.05 us | 1,812 B |
| Static | 100000 | Class | 1,530.50 us | 123.061 us | 362.849 us | 1,499.05 us | 1,711 B |
| NonStatic | 100000 | Struct | 1,024.84 us | 86.955 us | 255.023 us | 913.40 us | 1,410 B |
| Static | 100000 | Struct | 1,040.97 us | 79.565 us | 229.563 us | 951.30 us | 1,309 B |

## TL;DR:

**No difference in performance** *(mean differences are within stderror!)*, while **reducing GC pressure**. No harm no foul! I'd suggest using this if your code is heavily object oriented to avoid hanging onto "dead" objects through a misbehaving lambda.